# How to stop Angular UI Router passing optional params from one route to completely different route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two different states for two different routes:

```
// Route1.js
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
      url: '/route1?someOptionalParams',
      reloadOnSearch: false,
      templateUrl: 'app/routes/route1/route1.html',
      controller: 'Route1Ctrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
});

// Route2.js
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('route2', {
      url: '/route2',
      templateUrl: 'app/routes/route2/route2.html',
      controller: 'Route2Ctrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
});
```

Within Route1 I use $location.search (e.g. `$location.search('someOptionalParams', 'yayParams');`) to update the loaded data for that route. However, when I click on the navbar, which utilizes `ng-href='\route2'` to go to Route2, the params come with. How do I prevent this behavior?

**Update**:
I've been able to isolate the issue to this code in route1:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
  doAsynchronousStuff();
});

function doAsynchronousStuff() {
  ...codey stuff...
  $location.search('someOptionalParams', 'newData');
}
```

The $locationChangeSuccess code will fire after I start changing routes, but before the route has changed, so I'm currently looking for an alternative way to have the code in it fire on location change or prevent it from firing when I'm navigating to an unrelated route.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ui-router` (which it appears you are), you can use `ui-sref` instead of `ng-href` and then specify the state along with the params.  For example:

```
<a ui-sref="route2({ id: 1 })">Foobar</a>
```

Leaving the params off will obviously cause no params to be passed.

More information about it here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a go.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve it. Additionally, even if I don't have any optional params when I'm on Route1, when I navigate to Route2, the optional param appears, so the URL becomes "website.com/Route2?someOptionalParams=". I'll dig around in this code base some more and see if I can come up with any other clues.

Comment: Add `params: { someOptionalParams: null }` in the `.state()` definition to set the "default", then it won't show unless defined

Comment: Doesn't work either. I think there's more set up to this issue than I initially listed, so I'm doing some digging. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Definitely works as I have used it in several apps.  If you put up a jsfiddle I can probably find what's wrong quickly.

Comment: I've posted a new question, since it seems to be a different issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561895/how-to-fire-event-after-parameter-change-but-not-when-navigating-to-a-new-route), but if you still feel you've got this I can definitely make a jsfiddle tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by checking the $location.path within the Route1 controller.

```
// In route1.controller.js
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
  if ($location.path() === '/route1'){
    doAsynchronousStuff();
  }
});
```

I feel that this is a sign that I'm likely using $locationChangeSuccess incorrectly, so I'll keep researching. I've posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561895/how-to-fire-event-after-parameter-change-but-not-when-navigating-to-a-new-route).