# How to fire function after parameter change, but not when navigating to a new route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to fire an event whenever the user navigates forwards or backwards through their browser history, but only while on a particular route. I've tried using `$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function...` within the controller for this route, but this will fire even if I'm navigating to a completely different route using the browsers forward and backward buttons.

I was able to prevent this behavior when navigating forwards through the browser history by checking `$location.path()` and only executing the code if it matched the route. Unfortunately, this doesn't work if navigating *backwards* through the browser's history to a different route. I've added some excerpts from the code below to clarify.

```
// How parameters are being updated
$location.search('folder', searchId);

// Listening for the change
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
  if ($location.path() === '/initialRoute') {
    doThings();
  }
});
```

When this code fails as I navigate back in my browser history to a different route, I end up stuck on the original route and the URL becomes `website.com/initialRoute?optional_params=`, which it should never be, rather than `website.com/routeInMyHistory`.

Recap: Works going forwards in browser history, but not back.